# Parse: Retrive all Objects where user is in a relation

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I have a Parse Object `Event` it contain a key `attendees`, a Parse [Relation](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Relation.html#) object. My question is how to retrieve all event where current user is in the attendees relation ? my current code is :

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Event).equalTo('attendees',currentUser)
query.find({
   success:function(list){
   }
})
```

Comment: The code you provided not working? If list size is equal to 100 and not all users, you should use query.limit(num) to get more results. In parse.com, max-limit is 1000. I haven't try max-limit of parse-server.

Comment: yes, the result is not what i expect . the list is empty so i guess no record fulfill the condition `where user is in the attendees relation`. Is it the right way to get them using `equalTo`?

Comment: currentUser is a Parse.User object and with id? Another situation is current user's ACL is not public read

Comment: yes current user is a Parse.user (the user loggedin in the app) and have ACL public.

Comment: How you define Event? var Event = Parse.Object.extend('Event')?

Comment: yes of course  `const Event = Parse.Object.extend('Event')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117224/discussion-between-chuntinglin-and-coyote).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query seems Ok, try to verify your data in DB.

cmd from mongo shell

```
db.getCollection('_Join:attendees:Event').find({'relatedId':currentuserId})
```